# Copy batch file

Tags: batch-file

When using a batch file to copy every file starting with a in a folder what is the difference between doing C:\windows\system32\A*.* and C:\windows\system32\A*

I used just A* but my classmates are saying we are supposed to use A*.* but they did the same thing

Comment: `*` is "any file", `*.*` is "any filename plus any extension". There is no difference in `cmd`, because `*` is "zero or more characters" (`file.extension` is equal to `file.<nothing>` when`extension` is `<nothing>`)

Comment: (when I remember correctly, the wildcard behaved differently in `MS-DOS` - maybe that's what the "supposed" thing came from)